# Understanding vars in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, immutability

I'm fairly new to Clojure and I'm having a difficult time understanding what's happening behind the scenes with the following code:

```
; Associate the symbol 'fruits to the value ["apple" "banana"]
(def fruits ["apple" "banana"]) ; returns the var #'user/fruits
(count fruits) ; returns 2

(def fruits ["cherry" "orange" "grapes"]) ; returns the var #'user/fruits
(count fruits) ; returns 3
```

1. Is each "def" form returning a NEW var data structure that's named #'user/fruits?
2. It seems like the symbol 'fruits is bound to a different var after each "def" form - is this because whatever structure that represents the binding is a mutable data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

[Namespaces](http://clojure.org/namespaces):

> Namespaces are mappings from simple (unqualified) symbols to Vars and/or Classes. Vars can be interned in a namespace, using def or any of its variants, in which case they have a simple symbol for a name and a reference to their containing namespace, and the namespace maps that symbol to the same var.

[Vars](http://clojure.org/vars):

> Vars provide a mechanism to refer to a mutable storage location that can be dynamically rebound (to a new storage location) on a per-thread basis.

So, both namespaces and vars are mutable. In the example you give, the first occurrence of `def` creates a new Var and interns it (i.e. adds a new mapping to it) in the current namespace. The second occurrence of `def` resets the root binding of the existing Var, without altering the namespace mappings.

When you evaluate some code that contains the symbol of a var that you've defined (assuming it's not shadowed by any local lexical bindings), the compiler first looks up the var mapped to that symbol, and then gets the current value for that var.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - just to confirm, when you say "resets the root binding of the existing Var", what you mean is that the Var now points to the new fruits vector, right? In other words, the Var has mutated and is now bound to a different data set, right?

Comment: Correct. And as Arthur points out, the fact that this mutability affects global state of the program means that you shouldn't be using `def` to alter Var root bindings except for when you're first initializing a namespace.

Answer (score 4):

For your first questions: No it is instead actually changing the value contained in the Var fruits rather than making a new one:

```
 user> (let [old-fruits #'fruits] 
         (def fruits ["cherry" "orange" "grapes"]) 
         (identical? old-fruits #'fruits))
true
```

If we save a reference to the fruits Var (`#'` is shorthand for referencing a Var itself, not its contents) then redefine it, the `identical?` function tells us these are the *same* object.

For the second question: Namespaces are a **mutable data structure that maps symbols to vars**. They are not persistent, in the sense that the rest of Clojure's data structures are, and are updated in place. It is worth noting that vars and namespaces are entirely distinct things. While namespaces provide name lookup and typically resolve names to vars they them selves have little to do with vars. You can store vars in anything you would like, and you don't strictly speaking have to use namespaces to keep track of your vars. Vars also provide more functionality than namespaces (or at least different functionality). They have per-thread binding so you can `bind` a var to a new value safely on one thread without the change affecting other threads.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is slightly misleading - re-setting the root binding of a Var doesn't alter the namespace map.

Comment: Is it far to say that both the var and the data structure representing the namespace bindings are both mutable data structures then?

Comment: Yes, though var's provide per-thread changes while namespaces do not. I'll edit the last paragraph to make this difference more clear and remove the sentence about not programming by setting the root values of vars. That really didn't belong in a paragraph about namespaces. Thanks again for the feedback